# Avoid start a paragraph after align environment

Tags: math-mode, align, paragraphs

I highlighted my problem in red. As you can see, the highlighted line start with a paragraph, but I do not want this. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

```
  \[ F: M \times [0,T) \longrightarrow N \]

  such that 

  \begin{align*}    \begin{cases}       \frac{\partial F}{\partial t} (p,t) &= H(p,t) \nu(p,t)\\

  F(M,0) &= M,

  \end{cases} \end{align*}

  where $\nu(\cdot,t)$ is the unit normal to $F(\cdot,t)$ pointing
  inward and $H(\cdot,t)$ its mean curvature.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without the code that produces the output it's pure guessing.

Comment: LaTeX never automatically starts the paragraph at that position, You have not shown your source but presumably you have a paragraph start marked up there?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the topic and I put the code,

Comment: please use  the code block `{}` button or triple backtick for code, but you have placed a blank line before the text, a blank line is always reported as `\par` and is forcing the new paragraph.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a blank line is not allowed in an `align*` environment.  Please try to make sure that what we copy from here matches what you have in your document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not leave a blank line after the `align`.

```
% alignprob.tex  SE 564034
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's some text. 
Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's some text. 
Here's some text. Here's some text. 

\begin{align}
  x^2 + y^2 &= z^2 \\
  x^3 + y^3 &< z^3 
\end{align}
Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's some text. 
Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's some text. 
Here's some text. Here's some text. 

\end{document}
```

As you have not shown any code that produces your problem I can only provide a general answer.

Answer (score 2):

A blank line orders TeX to start a new paragraph. For this reason, they are disallowed in math displays (and produce errors).

There's a better way to isolate displays in the input text:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
F: M \times [0,T) \longrightarrow N
\]
such that
\[
\left\{
  \begin{aligned}
  &\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} (p,t) = H(p,t) \nu(p,t)\\
  &F(M,0) = M,
  \end{aligned}
\right.
\]
where $\nu(\cdot,t)$ is the unit normal to $F(\cdot,t)$ pointing
inward and $H(\cdot,t)$ its mean curvature.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I used `\left\{` and `\right.` instead of `cases`, because this would add some unwanted space at its right.

Also the `&` in `cases` is used to introduce conditions, not for aligning equations. Better using `aligned` for such a case. You can see that I placed `&` at the beginning, which provides left alignment: there is no reason for aligning those equals signs, that bear no relation to each other. Perhaps in this *particular* case one could strive for alignment, but just because the left-hand sides happen to have approximately the same width. If the second line had been `F(0)=M`, alignment of `=` would leave a puzzling hole.

[image]

Compare with

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would group both equations and use `\shortintertext` this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{esdiff}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{gather*}
  F: M \times [0,T) \longrightarrow N \\
\shortintertext{such that}
  \begin{cases}\begin{aligned}
  \diffp{F}{t} (p,t) &= H(p,t) \nu(p,t)\\[1ex]
  F(M,0) &= M,
\end{aligned} \end{cases}\\
\shortintertext{where $\nu(\cdot,t)$ is the unit normal to $F(\cdot,t)$ pointing inward and $H(\cdot,t)$ its mean curvature.\vskip-1.67\belowdisplayskip}
\end{gather*}

\lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Some extra spacing is needed in the `cases` environment. I see no reason for `\shortintertext`; use simply two `equation*` environments.

Comment: @egreg: Oh! yes. I focused on the spacing with text after gather* and didn't even notice it. I'll fix it in a moment. Thank you for pointing it!